# Does the gradient always point outward of a level surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function, with $a\in \mathbb{R}$ a regular value of $f$.

Let $M=f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$. Then $M$ is an $n$-manifold with boundary, whose boundary is $\partial M=f^{-1}(a)$.

Let $p\in \partial M$. Then $T_p\partial M=\{\nabla f(p)\}^{\perp}$.

> **Question**: Does $\nabla f(p)$ point outwards of $\partial M$?

I know it's not true if we take the interval the other way around. E.g. $-1$ is a regular value of $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$, but the gradient of $f$ points inwards of the boundary of $f^{-1}([-1,+\infty))$ which is $S^1$.

In fact, by symmetry, if the answer to the question is positive, I suspect that if we take $M=f^{-1}([a,+\infty))$ then $\nabla f(p)$ always points inwards of $\partial M$.

Comment: @Mercy: it's a 2-dimensional manifold with boundary, as I stated. This is a known result. For example, it's essentially lemma 1 in page 12 of Milnor's Topology from the differentiable viewpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to formulate my own proof of this theorem. I give full detail below.

**Definition**: Let $M$ be an $n$-manifold with boundary, $p\in \partial M$ and $\varphi:U\subset \mathbb{H}^n\to M$ a parametrization such that $\varphi(q)=p$. We say that $v\in T_pM$ is *inward-pointing* (resp. *outward-pointing*) if it is of the form $d\varphi_q(v_0)$ with $v_0\cdot e_n>0$ (resp. $v_0\cdot e_n<0$).

Let's check that this definition does not depend on the choice of parametrization, and at the same time give a useful criterion.

**Theorem**. Let $M$ be an $n$-manifold with boundary, $p\in \partial M$ and $v\in T_pM$. The following are equivalent:

1. There exists a parametrization $\varphi:U\to M$ such that, if $\varphi(q)=p$ and $v=d\varphi_q(v_0)$, then $v_0$ is such that $v_0\cdot e_n>0$.
2. $v\not\in T_p\partial M$ and there exists a curve $\alpha:[0,\epsilon)\to M$ such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=v$.
3. For every parametrization $\varphi:U\to M$ we have that, if $\varphi(q)=p$ and $v=d\varphi_q(v_0)$, then $v_0$ is such that $v_0\cdot e_n>0$.

*Proof*: ($1 \Rightarrow 2$) Define $\alpha:[0,\epsilon)\to M$ as $\alpha(t)=\varphi(q+tv_0)$, taking $\epsilon$ small enough for $q+tv_0$ to be in $U$ for all $t$. Then $\alpha(0)=p$, and by the chain rule, $\alpha'(0)=v$.

($2 \Rightarrow 3$) Let $\varphi:U\to M$ be a parametrization with $\varphi(q)=p$ and $v=d\varphi_q(v_0)$. Since $\alpha(0)=p\in \varphi(U)$, we may suppose that $\alpha([0,\epsilon))\subset \varphi(U)$, taking a smaller $\epsilon$ if necessary. We can define then a curve $\beta:=\varphi^{-1}\circ \alpha:[0,\epsilon)\to U$ with $\beta(0)=q$ and $\beta'(0)=v_0$.

Now, $\beta'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\beta(t)-q}{t}$. But $\beta(t)-q\in \mathbb{H}^n$ for all $t$, therefore $\beta'(0)=v_0\in \mathbb{H}^n$. Since we further assumed that $v\not\in T_p\partial M$, then $v_0\not\in \partial \mathbb{H}^n$, whence $v_0\cdot e_n>0$.

($3 \Rightarrow 1$) It is obvious. $\blacksquare$

**Theorem**. Let $f:M\to N$ be a differentiable function between manifolds with boundary. Let $p\in \partial M$ and $v\in T_pM$. If $v$ is inward-pointing, then $df_p(v)\in T_{f(p)}N$ is inward-pointing.

*Proof*: Let $\alpha:[0,\epsilon)\to M$ be a curve such that $\alpha(0)=p$, $\alpha'(0)=v$. Consider $f\circ \alpha:[0,\epsilon)\to M$. We have $f(\alpha(0))=f(p)$, and by the chain rule, $(f\circ \alpha)'(0)=df_p(v)$. Therefore $df_p(v)$ is inward-pointing. $\blacksquare$

**Theorem**: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function with $a\in \mathbb{R}$ a regular value. So $M=f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is a manifold with boundary such that $\partial M=f^{-1}(a)$. Let $p\in \partial M$. Then $\nabla f(p)$ is outward-pointing.

*Proof*: We first observe that $\nabla f(p)\not\in T_p\partial M$, because $T_p\partial M=\{\nabla f(p)\}^\perp$. Assume by contradiction that $\nabla f(p)$ is inward-pointing.

By considering $f|_M:M\to (-\infty,a]$, by the previous proposition we conclude that $df_p(\nabla f(p))\in \mathbb{R}$ is inward pointing to $(-\infty,a])$. Explicitly, this means that $df_p(\nabla f(p))<0$.

Indeed, a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}$ is inward-pointing to $(-\infty,a])$ if and only if $v\neq 0$ and there exists a curve $\alpha:[0,\epsilon)\to (-\infty,a]$ such that $\alpha(0)=a, \alpha'(0)=v$. Since $\alpha(t)\leq a$ for all $t$, then $v=\alpha'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\alpha(t)-a}{t}\leq 0$, therefore $v<0$.

We have thus that $df_p(\nabla f(p))<0$. We reach a contradiction, since $df_p(\nabla f(p))=\nabla f(p)\cdot \nabla f(p)=\|\nabla f(p)\|^2>0$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

By assumption $f(p)=a$ and $\nabla f(p)=: n\ne0$. For $X\in T_p$ we have
$$f(p+X)-f(p)=n\cdot X+o\bigl(|X|\bigr)\qquad(X\to0)\ .$$
Now put $X:= \lambda n$ with $\lambda>0$. Then $|X|=\lambda|n|$ and therefore
$$f(p+\lambda n)-f(p)=\lambda|n|^2+o(\lambda|n|)=\lambda |n|^2\bigl(1+o(1)\bigr)\qquad(\lambda\to0+)\ .$$
It follows that $f(p+\lambda n)>f(p)=a$ for all suitably small $\lambda>0$, which implies that $n$ points to the outside of $M$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll read it carefully. One minor thing though, I'm not used with the o-notation. I could read about it, but perhaps you wouldn't mind phrasing it differently, in which case I would be very grateful :)

Comment: @Bruno Stonek: I've edited my post slightly; but you better get accustomed to the $o$-notation.

Comment: What do you mean by "$X\in T_p$"? What is $T_p$?

Comment: Okay, whatever that is, taking $X=\lambda n$ works fine. I get it now, that does it. Thanks! I hadn't thought of proving the assertion by proving that $p+n\not\in M$, I was thinking of the definition which is a bit unmanageable.

Comment: In that last comment, I should have said: $p+\lambda n\not\in M$ for all $\lambda>0$ sufficiently small.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with your interpretation that the gradient of your example function $f = -x^2 -y^2$ points inward.  The manifold $M$ is everything outside of the unit sphere.  To me, saying the gradient points inward means it points *into* the manifold.  Instead, the gradient points *out* of the manifold.  It just so happens that out of the manifold is radially *towards* the origin.

It may be you drew this conclusion because you originally defined the manifold as the set of points such that $f$ takes on *no more than* the value of $a$, but then you changed to consider the set of points corresponding to $f$ *no less than* the value of $a$ at the end of the question.  Reversing these notions reverses what you consider to be part of the manifold.

Edit: I see why you explored that case then.  Then yes, as long as you define the manifold to contain points where $f < a$, the gradient will point to where $f$ increases and hence takes on values greater than $a$.  This is outward to the manifold when the manifold is defined in this way.

Comment: The example given at the end is just to illustrate that, if we change the premise, then the conclusion fails. The manifold $f^{-1}([-1,+\infty))$ is the standard ball, its boundary is $S^1$, but the gradient points inward.

Comment: @BrunoStonek I see what it is you were asking now, and I have added a section to my answer as appropriate.

Comment: When it is defined how? The definition I'm using of an outward pointing vector is the standard one, i.e. if $M$ is an $n$-manifold with boundary, $p\in \partial M$ and $\varphi:U\subset \mathbb{H}^n \to M$ is a chart such that $\varphi(0)=p$, then $v\in T_pM$ points outwards of $\partial M$ if it is of the form $d\varphi_0(v)$, where $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is such that $v \cdot e_n$ is greater than zero.

Comment: Forgive me, I meant to say when the *manifold* is defined in this way. As you pointed out, the gradient may not point outward when the points lying in the manifold correspond to values of $f$ greater than $a$. Whether it is outward or inward depends on how the manifold is chosen to correspond to the scalar field's values.

Comment: Ok, but could you give a proof of it? Thanks.